# Activity's background become black when i entered in activity or onLongPress of Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, baseadapter, layout-inflater

I am trying to implement one `ListView` in activity. In my XML there is a `ListView` to fill that `ListView` data I have invoked one `WebService` in `AsynkTask`. I have used `BaseAdapter` to set that `ListView`. Now, Whenever I came on that activity the background becomes black for fraction seconds of time and than disappear. Same things happened when I longpress on `ListView`. The screen shot had attached with this question as well as following are the code that I have implemented.

**Main Activity's XML** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.agraeta.user.btl.ComboOfferListActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@color/strip_bg"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:text="COMBO OFFERS"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/list_comboOffers"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java File Of Main Activity** :

```
public class ComboOfferListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback<ComboOfferData> {

ListView list_comboOffers;
ComboOfferListAdapter offerListAdapter;
List<ComboOfferItem> offerItemList=new ArrayList<>();
AdminAPI adminAPI;
Custom_ProgressDialog dialog;

String userID="";
String roleID="";
AppPrefs prefs;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_combo_offer_list);

    prefs=new AppPrefs(this);
    adminAPI=ServiceGenerator.getAPIServiceClass();
    dialog=new Custom_ProgressDialog(this,"Please Wait...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    userID=prefs.getUserId();
    roleID=prefs.getUserRoleId();

    if(roleID.equals(C.ADMIN) || roleID.equals(C.COMP_SALES_PERSON) || roleID.equals(C.DISTRIBUTOR_SALES_PERSON)){
        roleID=prefs.getSubSalesId();
        userID=prefs.getSalesPersonId();
    }

    fetchIDs();
    setActionBar();
}

private void fetchIDs() {
    list_comboOffers=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_comboOffers);
    offerListAdapter=new ComboOfferListAdapter(offerItemList,ComboOfferListActivity.this);
    list_comboOffers.setAdapter(offerListAdapter);
    list_comboOffers.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    list_comboOffers.requestFocus(0);
    list_comboOffers.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);






    dialog.show();

    Log.e("UR",userID+"-->"+roleID);

    Call<ComboOfferData> offerDataCall=adminAPI.comboOfferDataCall(userID,roleID);
    offerDataCall.enqueue(this);

}

private void setActionBar() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_design);

    View mCustomView = mActionBar.getCustomView();
    ImageView image_drawer = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.image_drawer);
    ImageView img_home = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.img_home);
    ImageView img_notification = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.img_notification);
    FrameLayout unread = (FrameLayout) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.unread);

    image_drawer.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_btl_back);

    img_home.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    img_notification.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    unread.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    image_drawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onResponse(Call<ComboOfferData> call, Response<ComboOfferData> response) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    offerItemList.clear();
    ComboOfferData offerData=response.body();
    if(offerData.isStatus()){
        offerItemList.addAll(offerData.getOfferItemList());
    }
    else {
        Globals.Toast2(this,offerData.getMessage());
    }

    Log.e("Size","-->"+offerItemList.size());

    offerListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<ComboOfferData> call, Throwable t) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    Globals.showError(t,this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
}
```

**Adapter Class** :

```
public class ComboOfferListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

List<ComboOfferItem> offerItemList=new ArrayList<>();
Activity activity;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public ComboOfferListAdapter(List<ComboOfferItem> offerItemList, Activity activity) {
    this.offerItemList = offerItemList;
    this.activity = activity;
    inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return offerItemList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return offerItemList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){

        holder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_combooffer_list,parent,false);

        holder.img_offerThumb=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_offerThumb);
        holder.txt_offerTitle=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_offerTitle);
        holder.card_comboOffer = (CardView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.card_comboOffer);
        holder.layout_combo = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_combo);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder= (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Picasso.with(activity).load(Globals.IMAGE_LINK+offerItemList.get(position).getImagePath())
            .into(holder.img_offerThumb);

    holder.txt_offerTitle.setText(offerItemList.get(position).getOfferTitle());

    holder.img_offerThumb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ComboOfferActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("combo_id", offerItemList.get(position).getOfferID());
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    holder.txt_offerTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ComboOfferActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("combo_id", offerItemList.get(position).getOfferID());
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Log.e("Called","-->"+offerItemList.size());
}

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView img_offerThumb;
    TextView txt_offerTitle;
    CardView card_comboOffer;
    LinearLayout layout_combo;
}
}
```

**Layout File For Adapter's View** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_comboOffer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:theme="@style/CardView.Dark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_combo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_offerThumb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_offerTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#f58634"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: Black Screen]

[image: Proper Screen]

Comment: there is no long press code on list view

Comment: i know. but when i hold my thumb on screen the same scenario happened. @AbhinavGupta

Comment: on simple click what will happen?

Comment: it will pass to another activity. @AbhinavGupta

Comment: on Combo offer activity?

Comment: yes @AbhinavGupta

Comment: so do you want to do?

Comment: just remove that black background when my activity is created @AbhinavGupta

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165868/discussion-between-abhinav-gupta-and-keval-shukla).